# android socket.io client not connecting with port

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect with nodejs group chat application running  on port 3000, I am using  socket.io-client:0.7.0  library in my project . It is not connecting to the server. 
I followed this tutorial

http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

package com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat;

```
import android.app.Application;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;

public class ChatApplication extends Application {

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
            options.port = 3000;
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.101",options);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: I am getting "Failed to connect " as Toast